# Referencing output of a template

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, google-deployment-manager

I have a Deployment Manager script as follows:
cluster.py creates a kubernetes cluster and when the script was run only for the k8 cluster creation, it was successful -- so it means the cluster.py **had no issues in creation of a k8 cluster**

`cluster.py` also exposes ouputs:
A small snippet of the cluster.py is as follows:

```
outputs.append({
            'name': 'v1endpoint' ,
            'value': type_name + type_suffix })

return {'resources': resources, 'outputs': outputs}
```

If I try to access the exposed output inside `dmnginxservice` resource below as `$(ref.dmcluster.v1endpoint)` I get an error as resource not found

```
imports:
- path: cluster.py 
- path: nodeport.py

resources:
- name: dmcluster
  type: cluster.py
  properties:
   zone: us-central1-a

- name: dmnginxservice
  type: nodeport.py
  properties:
   cluster: $(ref.dmcluster.v1endpoint)
   image: gcr.io/pr1/nginx:latest
   port: 342
   nodeport: 32123



ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in Operation [operation-1519960432614-566655da89a70-a2f917ad-69eab05a]: errors:
- code: CONDITION_NOT_MET
  message: Referenced resource yaml%dmcluster could not be found. At resource
    gke-cluster-dmnginxservice.
```

Comment: Hello, Can you provide as well the cluster.py and nodeport.py if no sensible data is contained? I would like to reproduce the issue with your code or a similar version.  You can past it here if if it is too long for stackoverflow https://gist.github.com/

Comment: the gist can be found here:

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/95a72abcf030be636827182b03a0f2af

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce a similar implementation and I have been able to deploy it with no issues making use of your very same sintax for the output.

I deployed 2 VM and a new network. I will post you my code, maybe you find some interesting hints concerning the outputs.

- The first VM pass as output the name for the second VM and use a reference from the network
- The second VM takes the name from the properties that have been populated from the output of the first VM
- the network thanks to the references is the first one to be created.

Keep in mind that:

> This can get tricky because the order of creation for resources is important; you cannot add virtual machine instances to a network that does not exist, or attach non-existent persistent disks. Furthermore, by default, Deployment Manager creates all resources in parallel, so there is no guarantee that dependent resources are created in the correct order.

I will skip that is the same. If you provide your code I could try to help you to debug it, but from the error code it seems that the DM is not aware that the first element has been created, but from the info provided is not clear why.

Moreover if I were you I would give a shot to explicitly set that `dmnginxservice` depends on `dmcluster` making use of the [metadata](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/create-explicit-dependencies). In this way you can double check if it is actually waiting the first resource.

**UPDATE**

I have been able to reproduce the bug with a simpler configuration basically depending on how I reference the variables, the behaviour is different and for some reason the property get expanded to `$(ref.yaml%vm-1.paolo)`, it seems that the combination of project and cluster references causes troubles.

```
#'name': context.properties["debug"],WORKING
#'name': context.env["project"],WORKING
 'name': context.properties["debug"]+context.env["project"],#NOT WORKING
```

You can check the configuration [here](https://gist.github.com/PaoloGallina/b079a44a2765d1e24d056c16f857f29d), If you need it.

Comment: Basically the k8.yaml is trying to reference the ouput property v1endpoint and when the google deployment manager attempts to create the dmnginxservice, I see an error that dmcluster was not found

Comment: also in the gist the property inside k8.yaml-- dmnginxservice is cluster and not clusterType

Comment: the link for the gist is okay now

Comment: I also have another gist with the expanded config 
https://gist.github.com/VarunkumarManohar/817604460d9688c84a10cd61cb12f7ff

To me it seems like the expanded config has issues ( please notice my comments in the gist)

Comment: I checked your configuration, I implemented the same and it is working correctly (making use of cluster and nodeports and passing similar parameters and outputs). I would advise you to test it step by step starting with hardcoded strings instead of parameters and as you proceed to add more complexity and you will spot for sure the bug in your code.

Comment: thanks for your update. I submitted a similar post on Deployment Manager issue list. The bug was reproducible at their end as well
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/issues/103#issuecomment-370593610

Comment: can you please post a gist of your configs @gallocedrone ?

Comment: Yes I will update my answer with my code as soon as I can, regarding your configuration I believe that the best you can do is waiting the official answer regarding the limitations.

Comment: Hello, I have been able to reproduce the issue and likely it is a bug or at least missing documentation, it was quite tricky to be honest to spot. I posted you the configuration that shows the fail with the 3 lines commented. Maybe you will need it since it is more readable and easier to be debugged. I think that a possible workaround for now is to hardcode the variables. I updated the answer with the info @Varunkumar

Comment: Thanks for your update @gallicedrone .. i think the issue is with the combination of cluster and project variables. Hopefully there will be fix from Google

Comment: Yes, I saw you were talking directly with a software engineer on GitHub. I believe it is a bug and therefore I cannot help you further. consider to up vote or accept if it was helpful, have a nice day!